# How to calculate TPS for a substrate based chain?

Tags: transactions, substrate-node

Let's say we have a 2 node network with PoA as consensus. In that case how to calculate TPS of this chain specifically?

Answer (score 1):

TPS is transaction per second, lets consider a scenario where:

The `block time` of chain is `3 sec` and there are `900 transactions` in a block so by this information you can calculate the TPS using following formula:

```
TPB(Transaction Per Block) = 900

TPS = TPB/block_time

    = 900/3

    = 300
```

So the TPS of above chain is 300

Comment: how to know how much transactions can fit in a block?

Comment: For that you can run a script and specify there how much transactions you want in that particular time or you can use a tool Apache Jmeter (https://jmeter.apache.org) which is used for load testing.